# Compiler's error in Codeblock: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported (Learn C the hard way ex19)

Tags: c

I'm learning: Learn C the hard way (ex19)
http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html
in "The game implementation" part there is this piece of code:

```
Object MonsterProto = {
.init = Monster_init,
.attack = Monster_attack
};
```

When compiled, it says: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported

Answer (score 3):

Designated initializers means initialize a struct by using the variable name of a member, like `.init = Monster_init`. Your book should mention that this feature is only available in the C99 standard or newer. If it doesn't, you need a better book.

You need to compile your code correctly. Tell it to use a newer version of the C standard, rather than a 25 years old version of it. In the gcc compiler, this is done by `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` or alternatively `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` (preferred if your compiler supports C11).

Comment: Please be more specific, I'm using codeblocks on Windows 7 with a GCC compiler and I don't know how to add any command like that. Please help, thanks

Comment: Ok now it's solved (I think) but another problem has popped up. In the Object_new function in "The Object Header file", there is a type called "size_t" and the compiler said "unknown type name size_t" , how can i fix that?

Comment: @DangManhTruong Codeblocks is an _IDE_, it supports a lot of compilers. You haven't mentioned which one you are using, so nobody can be more specific.`size_t` is found in stddef.h.